# How do I change the display name of an independant watchOS app?

Tags: apple-watch, watchos, watchos-6, cfbundledisplayname, apple-watch-standalone

I've tried changing the Display Name, the Bundle Name, and the Product Name but nothing seems to work. Every answer I've seen on here is referring to watch apps that have an iOS counterpart, not standalone independent watch apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done by changing the "Bundle display name" value in the Info.plist file in the WatchKit app folder.